# Troubleshooting help? PiZ2 - USB not working

Tags: usb, hardware, mouse, pi-zero-w-2

I just got a new Raspberry Pi Zero 2W, and setup a bootable 32G card no problem.

On first boot, I see the Setup screen via HDMI, and I can SSH into the pi-user from my PC.

But it is not responding at all to a USB Mouse and Keyboard. They are both connected via a big Powered USB Hub, so I doubt power is the issue. The red-light on the mouse is not on, nor does the keyboard show CapsLock or NumLock when pressed.

I'm beginning to suspect the USB port may be DOA, but is there anything else I can check/configure/test/work on?

Very much appreciate any ideas or help!

---

Since Bravo suggested `lsusb`, the output is below.
Also, I tried the mouse and keyboard individually (without any hub), and neither worked, which is why I originally suspected a lack of sufficient power and tried the powered hub.

```
pi@Pi2:~ $ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

pi@Pi2:~ $ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=dwc_otg/1p, 480M
pi@Pi2:~ $ lsusb -v

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Single TT
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1d6b Linux Foundation
  idProduct          0x0002 2.0 root hub
  bcdDevice            5.10
  iManufacturer           3 Linux 5.10.63-v7+ dwc_otg_hcd
  iProduct                2 DWC OTG Controller
  iSerial                 1 3f980000.usb
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0019
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
      bInterfaceSubClass      0
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
      iInterface              0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0004  1x 4 bytes
        bInterval              12
```

Comment: which USB port did you connect? ... i think that only one has data lines

Comment: I'd suspect the powered hub if the light isn't even on on the mouse - you can confirm this by, for example, attaching just the mouse (or just the keyboard) to the pi - if it works directly connected, then the issue is the USB hub - perhaps the pi doesn't recognise it - since you can ssh into the pi, you can check what the pi recognises on the USB port by running `lsusb` or `lsusb -t` or `lsusb -v` for even more details

Comment: so, with mouse/keybaord directly connected, you also don't get anything other than the root hub?

Comment: As @jsotola suggested, I had the Power and the Mouse/Keyboard reversed.   I swapped them, and it works fine.  I have dishonored myself with this stupid mistake.  Thank you!